# How do i increment a int variable by another int variable?

Tags: c++

Let me first start off that I'm very new to c++ and brand new to stackoverflow. 
Hi all, I’ve been trying to figure this out all day. I’m trying to update the variable  “real_total” by the variable “playerTotal” in the function below. However all its doing is just making them equal. When I cout << real_total << playerTotal << endl; I get the same number, which is correct for the users first guess, but their second guess its like “real_total” resets back to 0 instead of holding the value of “playerTotal”. I’m fairly certain it has something to do with my loop or the placement of my statements. Any help would be appreciated.

```
void update_total (string str, char& letter, int num, bool& roundover, int& playerTotal){
   int found = 0, real_total=playerTotal;
   for(int i=0; i < str.length(); i++){
      if(str.at(i) == letter){
        found = found + 1;
      }
   }
   playerTotal = num * found;
   real_total =+ playerTotal;
   cout << real_total << playerTotal << endl;
   cout << "There were " << found << " of those in the phrase. Your total earnings is $" << playerTotal << endl;
   cout << "Total game winnings is $ " << real_total << endl;
   if(found == 0){
      cout << "You guessed incorectly:(" << endl;
      roundover = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Please try to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: Off topic: Just dumb luck I saw this, but in `int random(int& num)`,  you do not want to `srand(time(NULL));`. `srand` will restart the the number generator with the current time as the seed. The time returned has a mimimum resolution of 1 second, so if called too quickly you will keep getting the same value. Recommended use of `srand` is to call it only once somewhere near the beginning of the program.

Comment: The issue is the `=+`, which is just assignment and (superfluous) unary +: it should be `+=`.

Answer (score 1):

The easy answer to this would be the following:

```
void foo() {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 10;

    // Increment i with j 
    i += j;
}
```

---

The += operator adds the value of the right operand to the left operand and assigns the left operand's new value to the variable.